# How to simplify multiple IDs to multiple function?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, asp-classic

I have the following code that checks the input of dates. I want users to key in dd/MM/YYYY. I will alert users if they key in dd/MM/YY. I am writing each javascript function for each input tags. How to simplify the javascript functions or I can't?

```
<input id="dt_join" name="dt_join" value="<%=dt_join%>" type="text" class="form-control" date-picker onblur="checkdt_join();">

<input id="dt_confirm" name="dt_confirm" value="<%=dt_confirm%>" type="text" class="form-control" datewotoday onblur="checkdt_confirm();">

<input id="dt_resign" name="dt_resign" value="<%=dt_resign%>" type="text" class="form-control" datewotoday onblur="checkdt_resign();">

function checkdt_join(){
    var input = document.getElementById("dt_join").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Date format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        }   
    }

function checkdt_confirm(){
    var input = document.getElementById("dt_confirm").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Date format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        }   
    }
function checkdt_resign(){
    var input = document.getElementById("dt_resign").value;
    var pattern =/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (pattern.test(input)==false){
        alert("Date format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Have a `checkdt(dt)` function and pass the id or even the object itself as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and dirty one: pass the input element by `this` in `onblur` attribute. (Removed attributes that are irrelevant to the question)

```js
function checkdt(el) {
  var input = el.value;
  var pattern = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;

  if (pattern.test(input) == false) {
    alert("Date format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
}
```

```html
<input value="01/01/2001" type="text" onblur="checkdt(this);" />
<input value="11/11/2011" type="text" onblur="checkdt(this);" />
<input value="12/12/2012" type="text" onblur="checkdt(this);" />
```

Clear and explicit one: use event listener

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date-checker").blur(function checkdt() {
    var input = this.value;
    var pattern = /^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

    if (pattern.test(input) == false) {
      alert("Date format is incorrect, please key in DD/MM/YYYY");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="01/01/2001" class="date-checker" type="text" />
<input value="11/11/2011" class="date-checker" type="text" />
<input value="12/12/2012" class="date-checker" type="text" />
```